# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist en tabla que sí existe

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Tengo una base de datos en la que cree usuarios con roles, y cada rol tiene ciertos privilegios de inserts, select, etc. dependiendo de los permisos de cada rol para cada tabla.
Pero cuando quiero hacer un select con un rol en una tabla en la que no tiene el privilegio de select, oracle dice que la tabla no existe, pero cuando hago select de una tabla a la que sí tiene privilegios de select, sí arroja las filas de esa tabla.
La idea es que cuando un rol haga select de una tabla en la que no tenga privilegios, el error debería de ser de tipo privilegios insuficientes, pero el error que arroja es de tabla o vista no existe. ¿Cómo resuelvo esto?
Por ejemplo, tengo la tabla unidad, y creo el usuario admin con todos los privilegios sobre esa tabla.
Tengo otra tabla llamada mantenimiento, y el usuario encargado, y encargado tiene los privilegios de select a la tabla mantenimiento, pero no tiene ningún privilegio para la tabla unidad.
Cuando hago `select * from unidad;` desde encargado, el error es tabla no existe, pero necesito que el error sea privilegios insuficientes

Comment: Para una sesión dada, el objeto no existe si no lo puede ver. Puedes registrar la solicitud con Oracle para cambiar el comportamiento del motor.

Comment: @Alfabravo y cómo hago eso?

Comment: Con una licencia comercial, registras tu solicitud por los canales de soporte. Pero no tiene mucho sentido, pues es un comportamiento que se ha mantenido desde (que yo sepa) hace muchas versiones. Oracle es a las BD lo que Microsoft es a los OS, entonces, más bien, por qué necesitas que el motor diga otra cosa? Será que necesitas ajustar el control de excepciones en tu capa de lógica de negocio para asimilar la no visibilidad como _no acceso_ a algo? Que tu capa de lógica de negocio suponga que el objeto existe no es del interés de la BD

Comment: @Alfabravo claro, entiendo y tienes razón, sin embargo, ¿es normal que un rol que no tenga privilegios de select sobre una tabla que sí exista en la base de datos, arroje un error de table does not exist en vez de privilegios insuficientes? porque la tabla existe, pero el rol no tiene el privilegio de acceder a la tabla, sin embargo dice que la tabla o vista no existe

Comment: Es que eso está mencionado como una de las causas del error `ORA-00942`: que el rol no tenga los permisos suficientes para acceder a la tabla. Hay varios [materiales](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00942.php) de [referencia](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00942_table_or_view_does_not_exist.htm).

Comment: si el rol no puede ver la tabla, para ese rol, la tabla no existe.. el error describe correctamente lo que pasa. Si te dijera que la tabla existe pero no para ese rol, un usuario mal intencionado podria saber todas las tablas que estan en tu sistema ;)

Comment: @gbianchi existe alguna forma para permitir que algún usuario vea las tablas aún sin tener el privilegio de hacer select?

Comment: y no.. si pudieras hacer eso, un usuario mal intencionado podria robarte la informacion de tu db... los roles y privilegios son por seguridad... todas esas cosas que estan preguntando, violan la seguridad.. porque querrias romper tu propio esquema de seguridad?? tal vez, tu problema sea otro, y estas tratando de solucionarlo de la forma equivocada???

Comment: Para mi, que confundiste roles de tu sistema, con los roles de base de datos... y ahi, es donde se te esta rompiendo todo....

Comment: No dañes la seguridad de la BD por no cambiar tu lógica. Digamos que tienes oracle >= 12c y le das GRANT READ al usuario pepito sobre la tabla juanito.tabla, luego con el usuario pepito haces `select * from juanito.tabla for update`. Ahí te va a dar el error de insufficient prvileges PERO vas a degradar el desempeño (porque para los usuarios que sí tienen GRANT SELECT va a hacer bloqueo exclusivo!) e igual tienes que modificar la aplicación. Como consejo, te estamos sugiriendo no seguir por ese camino.

Comment: No entiendo cómo esta conversación llegó tan lejos...

Comment: @Arriel es verdad! Con prontitud! Al [chat]!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema no es con los privilegios sino con los sinónimos.

Cuando una tabla está en un esquema, aunque el usuario tenga privilegios sobre esa tabla no lo va a encontrar si no la llama correctamente, es decir nombreDeEsquema.tabla

En tu caso si el usuario encargado tiene privilegios sobre la tabla prueba a hacer ésto:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM ADMIN.UNIDAD;
```

Si ésto te funciona puedes crearte un sinónimo a esa tabla

```sql
CREATE SYNONYM UNIDAD FOR ADMIN.UNIDAD;
```

Después ya te funcionaría el select que decías

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM UNIDAD;
```